# JSON, response in unicode or binary

Tags: python, json

Can anyone help me to grasp this paragraph :

***• JSON and XML have good support for Unicode character strings (i.e., humanreadable text), but they don’t support binary strings (sequences of bytes without
a character encoding). Binary strings are a useful feature, so people get around
this limitation by encoding the binary data as text using Base64. The schema is
then used to indicate that the value should be interpreted as Base64-encoded.
This works, but it’s somewhat hacky and increases the data size by 33%***

If i understand well, for example i use a REST API on my equipement to get some information with python.
For each response, it's in JSON and it's in unicode format.
So OK
But i don't really grasp the story of binary string.
Is it the fact that each character is not in UTF8 format ?
Why my equipement don't response in JSON encoded in byte and not in unicode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON and XML are text formats. They're designed to be readable by people, displayed and manipulated with typical text editors like `vi`, `emacs`, or `edlin`, using whatever character encoding scheme is convenient for the platform. All the character encoding schemes in use, however, have some data patterns that are not allowed to represent characters -- for instance, they may have a pattern that indicates "end-of-string".

If you want to include completely arbitrary data in JSON or XML, you need a way to encode that data in valid text strings and indicate the text is not the actual data you want to use. Base64 is one way of doing that encoding, and it is commonly used for this purpose. The disadvantages are the overhead of doing the encoding and decoding when writing or reading the data, the encoded text string is slightly larger than the original arbitrary binary, and that you have to remember to do the encoding and decoding.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON specification has no way to represent binary data natively, it only supports ASCII and Unicode encoded data. [Base64 Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) provides a way to represent arbitrary binary data as ASCII data by representing all bytes with ASCII characters in base 64. To read a binary object from JSON in which it is base64 encoded, you must first [decode it](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) .

Here is an example of encoding a python pickle object in base64 to be packed in a json payload.

```
import json
import base64
import pickle

binary_data = pickle.dumps([1,2,3])  # Binary python Pickle Object
encoded = base64.b64encode(binary_data).decode()  # UTF-8 String Representation
payload = {"binary_object": encoded}
my_json_object = json.dumps(payload)
print(my_json_object)
# Prints: {"binary_object": "gANdcQAoSwFLAksDZS4="}

read_data = json.loads(my_json_object)  # Read Json Data in
my_list_pickle = base64.b64decode(read_data["binary_object"])  # Decode Base64 Object
my_list = pickle.loads(my_list_pickle)  # Load Pickle Object
print(my_list)
# Prints: [1, 2, 3]
```

As for why your application is not responding with the format you want I don't know since you don't provide your application.